# Can we create a webhook using Partner Wsdl in Salesforce?

Tags: apex, trigger, webhooks

I want to create a webhook(trigger), whenever some object got inserted, deleted and updated and notification comes to my external server. So, I can do more action further with  my data. Is it possible using Partner Wsdl. If not can you please suggest me how to implement webhook for multiple organisation?

Comment: You want to send message or receive it?

Comment: The Partner WSDL is for SOAP calls *into* Salesforce. You can write Apex code to call an outside HTTP webhook, and you can also write a webhook in Salesforce, but those are distinct from the WSDL. I'm not sure what you mean by "multiple organization".

Comment: WSDL is not relevant here. Sounds like in the simplest form, you need [outbound messages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_managing_outbound_messages.htm&type=5) here.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal my server will listen.

Comment: You need outbound messages as suggested by JD, though you cannot fire outbound messages on delete

Comment: can't we create apex class and trigger in combination and have outcalls?

Comment: Yes, you can. But then you have to move your callout to future / queuable method. Which does not sound that bad, but there is hard limit 250K future calls a day. if its is within your org requirement you can.

Comment: If you can make the 3rd party server to adopt PUB - Sub model, you can leverahe use of Platform Events.7

Comment: I have seen platform events also but I didn't find any way to create platform event automatically or through API. If there is anyway to create dynamically?

Comment: For apex callout Can we dynamically create apex class and trigger in enterprise org also.